# Como hacer para que el modal de bootstrap no me pueda refrescar los datos al momento de guardar información

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

como hacer para que mi modal en bootstrap que me guarda información en la bd no me refresque la página inicial, tengo un formulario inicial y a la mitad de ingreso de los datos, tengo un button en modal con bootstrap que también guarda cierta información, pero, cuando le doy guardar y cierra el modal, me refresca el formulario principal y pierdo los datos ingresados anteriormente.

Codigo del modal para registrar información:

```
if (isset($_POST["monto1"])) {
         $datosController = array(
            "monto" => $_POST["monto1"],
            "fechaVencimiento" => $_POST["fechaVencimiento1"],
            "valor" => $_POST["valor1"],
            "numberClient" => $_POST["numberClient1"]
         );
         ModelCalendarioCuotas::calendarioCuotasModel($datosController);
      }
```

Codigo del modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="calendarioCuotaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="calendarioCuotaModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">CRONOGRAMA DE CUOTAS</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" id="cerrarModal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="tableCuotas" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead class="thead-dark">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                                        <th scope="col">MONTO</th>
                                        <th scope="col">FECHA VENCIMIENTO</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="cuerpoModal">
<tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" id="monto" name="monto1"></th>
        <th>
            <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaVencimiento" name="fechaVencimiento1" class="btn btn-primary" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><span class="far fa-calendar-alt"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Guardar">
                        <?php $sale = new ControllerCalendarioCuotas();
                        $sale->registrarCuotasController(); ?>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: El cuerpo de la tabla está vacío, entonces, lógicamente lo estás generando de acuerdo a algún evento y es ahí donde deberías buscar la forma de mantener los datos.

Comment: Si Trilby, tienes razón, lo consigo de esta manera: